# jQuery including issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

i have a problem with including jQuery, i have always done it like this and it has worked, until now... Tell me what have i done wrong. I also suspect it might be because i'm not on my laptop, but i visited one site that i had made earlier and the jQuery there worked. It might also be, that i don't have the right version of jQuery or something.
At the side that i hade made earlier i had used the jQuery load function:

Link to the site i had made earlier(look at the source code):http://www.laksyvihko.tk/read/

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Crêperie - Le Kerouac(Page d'accueil)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn").click(function()
{
    alert('jQuery works');
    //$("#navigation").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="responsiveContainer">
<div id="header">
<h1>Le Kerouac</h1>
</div>
<hr id="headerSeparator">
<div class="collapse">
<hr class="collapseHr">
<hr class="collapseHr">
<hr class="collapseHr">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navUl">
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#"><p>Page d'accueil</p></a></li>
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#"><p>Evénements</p></a></li>
        <li id="navLi"><a class="navA" href="#"><p>Contactez nous</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="siteContent">
<button id="btn">Alert</button>
<h3>Bienvenue sur le site de la Crêperie - Le Kerouac.</h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a `document.ready` handler and it works just fine

Comment: Or better, move your `script` tags to the end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag, where they belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button may not be fully loaded when you call your script. You have 2 solutions :

- placing your actual script at the bottom of your page (just before `</body>`)
- Adding DOM load event before binding  `click` to your button like folling :

  ```
  $(function() { /* DOM loaded event handler */
      alert("Hello world");
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok putting document.ready worked. What a stupid little mistake.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to you html page  section. You will get jquery lib `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` .Remember one thing the above code is downloading jquery code from server. You must and should have internet connection to test your application.

or else download jquery file from **http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js** this link and place it in your project use it in your project. One thing you should remember specify correct path then only jquery lib loads.

Kept you click function in document ready function will identify your onclick

```
$(function() { 
    // keep your onclik code here
});
```

Thank you.